# Does SSRS 2008 support Page breaks/Page Names?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, page-break

I made a report using Visual Studio Report Builder and had two datasets for two tables and had them exported on two Worksheets when exporting to Excel, with the help of Page breaks and Page names.

On Visual Studio, the report runs perfectly. But when uploading it to the SSRS Report Server, I get an error message:

> The report definition is not valid. Details: The element 'Tablix' in
>   namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition'
>   has invalid child element 'PageName' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition'.
>   List of possible elements expected: 'TablixCorner, TablixBody,
>   TablixColumnHierarchy, TablixRowHierarchy, LayoutDirection,
>   GroupsBeforeRowHeaders, RepeatColumnHeaders, RepeatRowHeaders,
>   FixedColumnHeaders, FixedRowHeaders, Style, SortExpressions,
>   ActionInfo, Top, Left, Height, Width, ZIndex, Visibility, ToolTip,
>   DocumentMapLabel, Bookmark, RepeatWith, CustomProperties, PageBreak,
>   KeepTogether, NoRowsMessage, DataSetName, Filters, DataElementName,
>   OmitBorderOnPageBreak, DataElementOutput' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition'
>   as well as any element in namespace '##other'.
>   (rsInvalidReportDefinition)

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. My SSRS version is 2008.

I usually have to use a hack to convert my 2015 generated report to make it compatable with my 2008 version SSRS by editing the .rdl file in notepad.

Is there a hack to allow pagebreaks in a report on SSRS 2008?

Comment: Report Builder is a stand-alone application that does not require Visual Studio, do you mean the Report Designer in VS2015?

Comment: Check to make sure the project is targeted at the correct report server version. (2008)

Answer (score 2):

Your error message tells you everything you need to know:

> invalid child element '**PageName**'
>
> **List of possible elements expected**: 'TablixCorner, TablixBody, TablixColumnHierarchy, TablixRowHierarchy, LayoutDirection, GroupsBeforeRowHeaders, RepeatColumnHeaders, RepeatRowHeaders, FixedColumnHeaders, FixedRowHeaders, Style, SortExpressions, ActionInfo, Top, Left, Height, Width, ZIndex, Visibility, ToolTip, DocumentMapLabel, Bookmark, RepeatWith, CustomProperties, **PageBreak**, KeepTogether, NoRowsMessage, DataSetName, Filters, DataElementName, OmitBorderOnPageBreak, DataElementOutput'

SSRS 2008 support page breaks, it just doesn't support page names.  Either get rid of the names and carry on with your *hack* method of ensuring compatibility, or simply set [Visual Studio to target SSRS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071175/can-i-control-the-version-of-new-ssdt-reports-in-visual-studio) and you should be fine.